# How to Add videos into one page automatically?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a library containing videos in **SharePoint**. I want to place these videos into one page, so it can easily played by user. And if anyone uploaded a new video into that library, I want that video to be automatically added to mentioned page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create an event receiver for your library.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/creating-simple-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/

Then adding the video webpart into page dynamically by c#.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-media-webpart-to-sharepoint-page-programmatically-using-server-side-object-m/